# Close the goroutine reading from a TCP connection without closing connection

Tags: sockets, go, nonblocking, channel, goroutine

I love the way Go handles I/O multiplexing internally which `epoll` and another mechanisms and schedules green threads (go-routine here) on its own giving the freedom to write synchronous code.

I know TCP sockets are `non-blocking` and `read` will give `EAGAIN` when no data is available. Given that, `conn.Read(buffer)` will detect this and **blocks the go routine doing a connection read with no data available in the socket buffer**. Is there a way to stop such go routine without closing the underlying connection. I am using a connection pool so closing the TCP connection won't make sense for me and want to return that connection back to the pool.

Here is the code to simulate such scenario:

```
func main() {
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9090")
    // Spawning a go routine
    go func(conn net.Conn) {
        var message bytes.Buffer
        for {
            k := make([]byte, 255) // buffer
            m, err := conn.Read(k) // blocks here 
            if err != nil {
                if err != io.EOF {
                    fmt.Println("Read error : ", err)
                } else {
                    fmt.Println("End of the file")
                }
                break // terminate loop if error
            }
            // converting bytes to string for printing
            if m > 0 {
                for _, b := range k {
                    message.WriteByte(b)
                }
                fmt.Println(message.String())
            }

        }
    }(conn)

    // prevent main from exiting
    select {}
}
```

What are the other approaches can I take if it's not possible:

1) Call `syscall.Read` and handle this manually. In this case, I need a way to check if the socket is **readable** before calling `syscall.Read`otherwise I will end up wasting unnecessary CPU cycles. For my scenario, I think I can skip the event based polling thing and keep on calling `syscall.Read` as there always be data in my use case.

2) Any suggestions :)

Comment: You want to return a connection to the pool as soon as there's no immediate read possible? That's very unusual, especially for TCP. What kind of connection is that, where you don't expect any network delays?

Comment: @Peter To be specific this is a redis connection. I subscribe for multiple channels on the same connection. I manually keep track of the channels subscribed on the redis connection. If the subscription count becomes 0, then i want to return the connection to the connection pool.

Comment: Hi! You could say, please: 1) why infinite loop without stop condition, known you that exists EAGAN? if is using connection pool why don't is getting of pool instead of conn direct in goroutine?

Comment: @AristofanioGarcia 1) Yeah my bad ! I should have put return conditions in the for loop 2) I am just omitting extra details.

Comment: I need of more details for help you! But first, you need of EAGAN-based stop condition for exit of goroutine without to close connection. After, if this connection backs to pool, the best way is pass pool to goroutine and to check connection.

Comment: @AristofanioGarcia For the `EAGAIN` based condition, I need to use the lower level `syscall.Read` and it won't be scalable to have so many for loops reading using `syscall.Read` if I do it without a polling mechanism like `epoll` with a level-triggered approach which I want to avoid here.

Comment: Oh! I understood what you want to avoid! But in this limited context I dont known as help you! Sorry!

Comment: @AristofanioGarcia thanks, not a problem.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15735?

Comment: Yes I have gone through it, the epoll approach is described over there which I want to avoid.

Comment: @dartrix, that sounds like you can get away with an appropriate ReadDeadline. Every time that deadline is reached, just check if anyone is still subscribed on that connection.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the suggestion let me try it, so I have to use `ReadFrom` instead of `Read`.

Comment: @Peter Thanks the approach worked !

Answer (score 1):

```
func receive(conn net.TCPConn, kill <-chan struct{}) error {
    // Spawn a goroutine to read from the connection.
    data := make(chan []byte)
    readErr := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        for {
            b := make([]byte, 255)
            _, err := conn.Read(b)
            if err != nil {
                readErr <- err
                break
            }
            data <- b
        }
    }()


    for {
        select {
        case b := <-data:
            // Do something with `b`.
        case err := <-readErr:
            // Handle the error.
            return err
        case <-kill:
            // Received kill signal, returning without closing the connection.
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Send an empty struct to `kill` from another goroutine to stop receiving from the connection. Here's a program that stops receiving after a second:

```
kill := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
    if err := receive(conn, kill); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}()
time.Sleep(time.Second)
kill <- struct{}{}
```

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, because the reading goroutine would still be blocked on `Read` even after you send to `kill`. However, the goroutine that handles incoming reads would terminate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, yeah this won't do any good in my case as when I reuse the connection, the data will be read in some other buffer which i can't access, for eg. `data` here.

Comment: @darxtrix Why not stash the connection back to the pool together with it's data & readErr channels? This way you can check for the `Read` result once you get the connection back from the pool, and not miss anything.